# How to get PHP to swap back slash to forward slash automatically in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, windows

I have the problem that Windows uses `\` as the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR and the code was written to use `\`.  Because of the nature of the application the code was replicated many times.

I would like to find a solution that does not require me to edit the code, since I now want to move the code to a Linux server. Linux only uses `/` as the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR so the code does not recognize it.

Is there a way to make Linux use both `\` and `/` like Windows without having to edit the code? i.e php.ini or cPanel?

Comment: just use `/` everywhere. PHP will auto-translate the native system one for you.

Comment: I believe you're out of luck here, having used `\\` ties you to a single platform (that is, Windows).

Comment: "some cases uses \ as the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR and the code was written to use \" ?

Comment: I wish i would have looked into this before writing the code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Meaning I wrote the code to use \... so Linux does not recognize it.

Comment: then you need to rewrite it, what do you expect?

Comment: Modify the code to use the constant (or the hardwired forward slash) and then test it thoroughly on Windows. If it works, it is likely to be OK for Linux. Though watch out for other gotchas, like case sensitivity on the filing system (Windows no, Linux yes).